# Passkit / passbook iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, passbook

Can I use Passkit and PassBook if my development target is 5.0? I'm a bit confused because passbook comes with iOS 6. But I can add the passkit Framework within Xcode. What will happen with devices using iOS 5? In which sdk passkit was added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't specifically checked - but you should be able to make the link a weak link, and then check at runtime.

Go to your project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries.

Then change the library you want to weak-link from "Required" to "Optional"

If you don't make it a weaklink it will fail to run on devices running iOS < 6.0

Answer (score 2):

It won't compile for a lower device. It shouldn't actually compile at all.
If it does compile it will through a warning telling you:

> PassKit.framework is not supported in iOS versions less than 6.0